# Are these 2 piecewise functions equivalent

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  e^{-(x+2)}&\text{if}\, -2 < x < \inf\\
  0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  e^{-x}&\text{if }\, 0 < x < \inf\\
  0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Are these 2 piecewise functions equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remembering function transformations. Suppose:

$$f(x)=e^{-x}\quad \quad f(x+2)=e^{-(x+2)}$$

$f(x+2)$ the parent function $e^{-x}$ shifted *to the left $2$ units*. So, it is not equal to the other piecewise function: the domains of each piecewise function encompass the same *curve*, but are not in the same place because the first is *transformed*. As an example, try plugging in some $x$-values, such as $x=1$:

$$e^{-(1+2)} \neq e^1$$